Clickable bar plots on a map with Shiny
I was wondering if anyone has any tips or has any sort of tutorial on the following problem of mine - I got the election results dataset found here. The idea would be to create a Quarto dashboard where I'd have the map of the US with either the states or counties (both or on separate tabs) and upon clicking, a bar plot with the results in the unit would appear.
Has anyone tried to do this in Shiny or should I look into other frameworks (possibly ObservableJS and so on)? And if so, does anyone have a good starting point?
